# Get anonymous/unnamed tuple-value by indirect index?

Tags: scala, tuples

Regard this

```
val oddOrEven = (odd, even)
```

`oddOrEven._1` would give "odd", while `oddOrEven._2` would give "even"

We basically get a tuple with "unnamed" members, if you will so.

But let's assume I wanted to get either odd or even, depending on some external data, like so:

```
val witness: Int = {numberOfPrevious % 2}
```

now, let's do this:

```
val one = oddOrEven._witness
```

This won't compile.

Is there some special syntax involved or is this simply not possible?

I got curious and wondered whether it was the compiler that could not deduce that the only possible values of `witness` would be 0 and 1 (but I thought that to be silly on my side, yet I had to try) and tried this:

```
val oddOrEven = (odd, even)
val witness: Int = {numberOfPrevs % 2}

val v = x match {
    case 0 => oddOrEven._1
    case 1 => oddOrEven._2
}
```

Yet again `val one = oddOrEven._witness` would not work

Then I dug deeper and found out that indeed the compiler would not check for exhaustion. Like:

```
val v = x match {
    case 1 => oddOrEven._1
    case 2 => oddOrEven._2
}
```

would still compile, although 2 was not possible and 0 was missing!

So, I know I am mixing things up here. I am aware that there are matches that are not what is called "exhausting" in my mothertongue, so the possible values are not deduced at compile-time, but at runtime (and indeed I would get a

> scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.Integer)
>   at runtime.

But, what I'm really interested in: Can I get "unnamed" tuples by an "indirect index" like I mean to?

Comment: No, not in a statically typed language like Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about keep it simple, like this:

```
val oddOrEven = (odd, even)
val witness: Int = {numberOfPrevious % 2} // Or any other calculation of index
oddOrEven.productElement(witness)
```

You loose type safety while productElement returns Any, but when you know the type  of members you can cast, like:

```
oddOrEven.productElement(witness).asInstanceOf[YourType]
```

I'm making assumption here that your odd and even values are of the same type, e.g:

```
sealed trait OddOrEven
case object odd extends OddOrEven
case object event extends OddOrEven
```

Then:

```
oddOrEven.productElement(witness).asInstanceOf[OddOrEven]
```

will give you correct type OddOrEven.

Btw. take a peek at [ScalaDoc for Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple2)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not do that. If you need an index, think about a `List` or a `Vector`.

But if you really want this and all of your tuple items are of the same type (for example `Int`) you could do:

```
 (even, odd).productIterator.collect { case x: Int => 2* x }.toList(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like `tuple.productIterator.toList(index-1)`, but if you want a list, it's probably a better idea to just use a list rather than converting a tuple to it.

And no, compiler doesn't try to figure out all possible ways your code can be executed in order to tell what possible values a variable could take.